# Specific olcAccess does not work for an OU in OpenLDAP

Tags: linux, permissions, ldap, openldap

On my OpenLDAP server, I would like the accounts in my "ou=partners" OU to have "read" permissions to all objects in "ou=abos". Here is the tree of my DIT :

[image: ditTree]

My olcAccess is allowed but does not grant the permission as I would like :

```
 olcAccess: {4}to dn.subtree="ou=abos,dc=MULTIPASS`,dc=LDAP" by dn.children="ou=partners,ou=accounts,dc=MULTIPASS,dc=LDAP" read
```

What is the correct olcAccess to write ? Can someone help me please ? Thank you.